# Excel pivot table showing values

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Is it possible to return and represent values in the table rather then count?
I need my table to return dates instead of count.

Please see the snapshot attached below:

[image: pivot table]

Answer (score 0):

You can choose others options instead of count, for example sum, min, max, ... it depend on what you want to show on the table. 
If you just use the pivot for have an unique list of fruit/variety you'll better use the "remove duplicates" button.

[image]

Comment: In my real table date is replaced by ID and i need the to be represented in the pivot table